Balanced graph partition with remainder
This question builds from the well known Balanced graph partitioning. Given a graph G=(V,E) we want to divide the vertices V into k partitions P_k such that they all contain the same number of vertices and some objective function (example - minimum cost inside partition/minimum cost between partitions/minimum number of edges between partitions) is optimised.
All neat and dandy plenty of algorithms exist for that. My question is what do we do if k is not a factor of |V|? Some remainder will exist. I know the general graph partition problem of finding partitions at most some size. But here I am still interested in finding balanced partitions, just with some remainder of nodes not included or alternatively only one partition is larger than the rest (containing the remainder).
So far I have not been able to locate a problem formulation of this sorts. Maybe I am looking in the wrong direction because I stuck to graph partitioning as a base for my search, but maybe it's an unrelated problem.
In any cases I would appreciate any and all directions on what I can explore in terms of known formulations/algorithms for this definition.
Thanks!

In general, balanced separator problems are defined such that a difference of one is tolerated exactly to address this issue

I have seen the exact formulation, that you are referencing, but it tolerates that all sets be some epsilon higher (so for example - split 17 nodes into 3 partitions, the typical algorithms allow for 6,6,5, but I am interested in only 7,5,5)
